# Recursive binary search program

Tags: recursion, binary-search

Here's my method for a recursive binary search. This is suppose to find a phone number from a sorted list, but it's only working for the first number in the file and says everything else is not found. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

```
static int binary (String num, String[] phone, int low, int high)
{
    if ((high - low) <= 1)
    {
        if (phone [low].equals (num))
        {
            return low;
        }
        else if (phone [high].equals (num))
        {
            return high;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (phone [mid].compareTo (num) > 0)
    {
        return binary (num, phone, 0, mid);
    }
    else if (phone [mid].compareTo (num) < 0)
    {
        return binary (num, phone, mid, high);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
if (phone [mid].compareTo (num) > 0)
{
    return binary (num, phone, low, mid-1);
}
else if (phone [mid].compareTo (num) < 0)
{
    return binary (num, phone, mid+1, high);
}
```

Also, you do more checks than are necessary:

```
static int binary (String num, String[] phone, int low, int high)
{
    if(low > high)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    int compare = phone[mid].compareTo(num);
    return compare > 0 ? binary (num, phone, low, mid-1);
        : compare < 0 ? binary (num, phone, mid+1, high);
        -1;
}
```